# Why does Pycharm keep telling me some of my variables aren't defined?

Tags: python

I'm trying to boost my experience in Python using a tutorial on how to make a calculator in Python that i found on youtube, here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-mvqlkHOHY . The reason why i ask here is because commenting is disabled there. The problem i have with my code is that no matter how identical my code is to his, PyCharm keeps telling me that the variable "side" in my functions i_calc() and button() is unfilled. 
Every time i click on the variable to highlight it, i can see a connection between the parameter and the value of the variable but not the same for the variable name.

Here's the code block that caused the problem:

```
from Tkinter import*


def i_calc(source, side):
    store_obj = Frame(source, borderwidth=1, bd=4, bg="powder blue")
    store_obj.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    return store_obj

def button(source, side, text, command=None):
    store_obj = button(source, text=text, command=command)
    store_obj.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    return store_obj
```

Comment: fix your indentation please. Just paste your code in, select it and press **Ctrl + K**

Comment: Ok, i'll do what i can.

Comment: while asking a question involving `python`, it is *essential* that you use proper indentation

Comment: Thanks, fixed it now ;).

Answer (score 0):

This means that when you called the function, you didn't input a value for side. (Or at least I assume so, since I can't look at the code where you called it.) You need to make sure when you call i_calc, you input 2 values.